# example of automorphisms such that it is proper class

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I have read [Automorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism).
So I had an interest in the following statement:
"If the automorphisms of an object X form a set (**instead of a proper class**), then they form a group under composition of morphisms."
For example, an automorphisms of proper class may be itself proper class.
However can an automorphisms over set be proper class?
I can't think of any example.

Question:
Is there example of automorphisms over set such that it is proper class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For some authors, in the definition of category, for any two objects $X$ and $Y$, $\text{Hom}(X, Y)$ is required to be a set. In particular, $\text{Hom}(X, X)$ is a set, and so $\text{Aut}(X, X)$ is a set (the subset of invertible elements).

However, the Wikipedia does not seem to require this. If we drop that requirement, we could make an example where $\text{Aut}(X, X)$ is a proper class. Here is a silly example: take a category with one object $X$ and declare that $\text{Hom}(X, X)$ is the [surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) with composition given by addition. Then every arrow is invertible, so $\text{Aut}(X) = \text{Hom}(X, X)$ is a proper class. (We're not using any properties of the surreal numbers here except that they're a proper class with a group-like operation.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just as you said, It seems wise that $\text{Hom}(X, Y)$ is defined to be a set.